# How to have Twilio remind texters that they opted out

Tags: twilio

We have a case of users not noticing in their chat history that they opted out, and sending us SMS and wondering why we are not responding. When this happens, our webhook is called and we receive the message, but we cannot respond, and the user is not notified that they are sending on a number they have blocked.

Is it possible to have Twilio let users know that the receiver cannot reply because they have them blocked?

Comment: When they opt out, make them aware of the consequences. Tell them what messages they continue to receive and which not. Be clear about privacy settings and they won't be confused. Don't try to circumvent privacy mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can [change your opt-out keywords, opt-in keywords, and their messages inside of a Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/tutorials/advanced-opt-out).
I would advise you to customize this to make it as clear as possible to your users what will happen when they do opt-out and how they can opt back in.

Other than that, you could communicate this issue using an alternative medium, but that may be confusing.